# Fails to map api response to pojo when enabling multidex

Tags: android, jackson, resttemplate, robospice, android-multidex

I'm writing an Android application with lots of dependencies and I needed to enable multidex because it exceeds the limit (65536k methods). I followed this [guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) and able to compile and run the application on my test device. The problem is I'm getting a nullpointerexception in Robospice RequestListener
for every api call that I make. I'm sure that the api is responding. It seems that the app fails to map the response to my pojo class.

Note: It's running fine before I enabled the multidex.

here is the request listener

```
 private class MyRequestListener implements RequestListener<PojoClass> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException e) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(PojoClass pojoClass) {
      // pojoClass <---- this is null
    }

}
```

here are my dependencies for rest and mapping

```
'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.14'
'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13' 
'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?